# Why Ranked Keywords Lead to the Homepage rather than to the Actual Article - as a result users couldn't get the things that they were looking for?

Tags: seo, blog, technical-seo, seo-audit, url-keywords

I am watching my Google Site KIt, Most of the traffic that we are getting to our Archive Pages and Homepage.

After some research, I found the problems:

When I search the entire title of my article, the URL to the article is showing.

SEE IMAGE: 01 FOR A BETTER UNDERSTANDING - [image: SEE IMAGE: 01 FOR A BETTER UNDERSTANDING]

But when I search the keyword.

I am ranking but rather than showing the URL to the article, it’s showing the URL of my homepage. SEE IMAGE: 02 FOR A BETTER UNDERSTANDING - [image: SEE IMAGE: 02 FOR A BETTER UNDERSTANDING]

That’s why I am getting a lot of traffic to the Homepage and Archive Pages I guess.

AND NOT GETTING ACTUAL TRAFFIC.

See, I am getting lots of traffic to Homepage and Archive Pages:
[image: SEE THIS IMAGE]

As a result, users couldn't get the things that they were looking for and bounced back from our site and we are not getting any positive results.

Answer (score 1):

Because your home page also has these words.
And Google has decided that the home page is a better match.

You have to tweak your phrases on both pages. Use a website tool to analyse your pages for keyword density.

Comment: As per your answer. I used a Keyword density tool and found that:

On the homepage, the keyword “Technoblade NFT has “COUNT: 3” and “DENSITY: 0.31%”.

But in the article, the keyword “Technoblade NFT has “COUNT: 25” and “DENSITY: 1.50%”.

So, according to that Article should be the best match, right?

Comment: Keyword density is an awful measure of relevance.  Having such a high density on your article page is probably hurting you.  Google is likely to see that as keyword stuffing.  You need to use keywords judiciously and prominently.  It is bad to repeat them more than a couple times.